# Adding Class-Path (sqljdbc4) to manifest file makes JAR unable to find/load main class Main

Tags: java, jar, cmd, classpath, program-entry-point

I've been having some strange problems with JAR creation from my project lately. I've been writing a simple Swing-application, a database frontend, but have not been able to build it as a jar through IntelliJ for a while now. First I got JNI errors, and then it couldn't find or load main class "Main", despite the fact that I have a very simple Main-class, called Main, with only the method main().

Today, I was looking into JAR-creation through the terminal, and decided to try doing it off of the .class files I had in my IntelliJ-project. I wrote a manifest.txt (tried with manifest.mf too), containing the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: C:\Users\mac\IdeaProjects\MWBSQLGUI\sqljdbc4.jar
```

I used this to make the JAR: `C:\mywork jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt dir1/*.class dir2/*.class`

Running the JAR produced the "could not find or load main class Main"-error.
The odd thing is, if I remove the class-path line from my manifest, jar creation goes smoothly, and I can run the application. It obviously throws exceptions wherever the depency was needed though, so it really doesn't help much. Any idea how I can incorporate the sqljdc4.jar? I've looked up a lot of manifest formatting articles, it seems like I'm doing it correctly. I've tried with newline(s) after the class-path line too...

Here's the CMD output from creating and trying to run the JAR with the Class-Path line in the manifest: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKMXQ.jpg

Contents of the Main class:

```
import View.MWBFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MWBFrame frame = new MWBFrame("MWB SQL Lookup");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh god, I figured it out. After a month of troubles with this, I just randomly noticed that some people put a \ before the C:\Program Files etc. in the Class-Path. This fixed it for me...

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue you did. I had assumed that the error referred to the class I was creating. Your discovery seems to indicate that it's a problem with the main class for the sql jdbc driver. I have a ton of questions.  First, what do you mean by 

some people put a \ before the C:\Program Files etc. in the Class-Path. 

I don't follow, can you elaborate?  Post the contents of your MANIFEST.MF?

Could you describe where your files go?  I use three folders, one for my jar, one for the driver, one for my class file.

Thanks. I could really use your help on this.